# Javascript get substring with multiple of the same characters

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the string:

```
var post = "[PostContent(postId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000, postName=My New House, picture=house.jpg, location=San Francisco)]"
```

What I'm trying to rip out is the UUID from the postId so the new resulting string just has the value:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

Thanks for the help!

Update:

Sorry for the incomplete question I've already tried:

```
var firstvariable = "postId=";
var secondvariable = ", postName=";
string.match(new RegExp(firstvariable + "(.*)" + secondvariable));
```

and

```
string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("postId=")+1,string.lastIndexOf(", postName"));
```

and

```
var regex = /(.*postId=\s+)(.*)(\s+, postName.*)/;
var newtext = string.replace(regex, "$2");
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: use `postId=([\w-]+)` regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```js
var post = "[PostContent(postId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000, postName=My New House, picture=house.jpg, location=San Francisco)]";

console.log(
  post.match(/postId=([\w-]+)/)[1]
)
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/1AuySZ/1)